# Javascript 3d array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, 3d

I have these 3 dimensional arrays :

[image: Click for Safari Scope Chain Result]

I then try to add a new row to the 2nd dimension using:

`drawTable[1].push([0,0,0,0,0,0])`

and the array updates to:

[image: Click for Safari Scope Chain Result]

I did not expect drawTable[0] to be affected, but looks like it gets a row to, perhaps to keep it "square"?

I then run the following code:

`drawTable[1][1]=[1,1,1,1,1,1].`

I would expect this to only change one line of 0's, but it seems to change it in drawTable[0] and drawTable[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpsrA.png) for some reason.

[image: Click for Safari Scope Chain Result]

Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: can you please show, how you initialized the arrays in the first place?

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried please ?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I think you’ve inserted the same array instance into drawTable twice. drawTable[0] and drawTable[1] are pointing to the same array. When adding to drawTable you must create a new array every time, and not use the same

Comment: @schteppe thank you.  This led me to a solution.  Should have come here sooner.   6 hours wasted.

Answer (score 0):

schteppe was correct.  I used drawTable.push(drawTable[0]) to create the second element of the drawTable array.  Apparently that makes them mutually dependent?

I changed to:

`drawTable[1]=drawTable[0].slice(0,drawTable[0].length)`

and the problem went away.